# Empty whitespace conversion in PDFClown

Tags: pdf, pdfclown

I'm having an issue when using the `TextExtractor` class in PDFClown, with occurrences of empty whitespace also known as a "discretionary newline". These characters are embedded randomly but ignored in Acrobat Reader. So, lines where these characters exist will show as a single line in Acrobat, but are broken into many lines when the text is extracted, if I specify `'\n'` as the newline character in `TextExtractor.ToString(...)`.

It appears that PDF clown simply takes any whitespace character and converts it into a single space, or `' '`. Is there a way to bypass this conversion, so that the original character is extracted instead?

Comment: Could you share a sample file and your exact code? I ask because it is even more likely that Adobe Reader makes something special when *ignoring* something than that PDF Clown does something special when *including* a new line character, but one needs to check.

Comment: @mkl I'll try to find a sample I can share. Unfortunately these are client's files I'm having issues with so I can't publish them.

Comment: *Unfortunately these are client's files I'm having issues with so I can publish them.* - In that case try and create a file with the identical problem. Probably there is a page (with that issue) in the client's file with some generic chit-chat which you can separate and publish.

Comment: @mkl Let me see what I can do and get back to you asap. Thanks for taking an interest.

Comment: @mkl I got to the bottom of it and posted an answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more research, it appears that the PDFClown library is very buggy. There are several issues:

- Converts most forms of space character to a single normal space
  character.
- Inserts spaces instead of newlines.
- If you attempt to use the provided overrides to insert your own character for spaces or newlines, the internal mappings of characters in the extracted array to boxes for each individual character gets destroyed.
- Cannot properly decode all embedded fonts.
- Since it cannot properly decode embedded fonts, it will silently omit characters from extracted text.
- Cannot reliably handle ligatures or decomposition of ligatures. Often silently dropped altogether from extracted text.

To come directly to the issue I had, you can detect and remove these "false" whitespace characters by checking their bounding rectangle to see if they overlap other non-whitespace characters, but given all the other issues with the library, my advice to use use PDFBox instead.

If you're using .NET and you'd like to use [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/), you can use [Tika On Dot Net](https://kevm.github.io/tikaondotnet/) which is the [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/) project brought over to .NET via IKVM.

Apache Tika is a collection of other libraries, include PDFBox. Tika On Dot Net currently has PDFBox 1.8.10 and also has a Nuget package to make adding to your project easy.

I had a project go 1.5 weeks over deadline because all of these issues were discovered half way through, which required a full rewrite. Just a heads up.

Comment: *No disrespect to the author, but PDFClown should have at best a beta version number.* - Actually a version 0.1.2 or even a 0.2.0 (which is scheduled for last July) is pretty beta'ish or even alpha'ish, isn't it?

Comment: @mkl Edited out, for some reason when I recalled seeing the version, I didn't remember the leading "0." ;) My bad.

Comment: No problem. Concerning the other issues, if you had had enough time, you could have made them individual questions here with sample files and the problems might have been solvable. But admittedly after deadline you never have enough time... ;)